# Can't save Entity Even there is no Errors in CakePhp3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I Have user table and when i want to save it  `save()` return null even when i debug `$user` there is no error..

```
'[errors]' => [],
```

This is my code :

```
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        $tmp_hash = md5(rand(0, 1000));
        $tmp_id = time();
        /* Save individual data */
        $user->id = $tmp_id;
        $user->first_name = (!empty($user_profile->firstName)) ? $user_profile->firstName : "";
        $user->last_name = (!empty($user_profile->lastName)) ? $user_profile->lastName : "";
        $user->username = (!empty($user_profile->lastName) && !empty($user_profile->lastName)) ? $user_profile->firstName . "." . $user_profile->lastName : "";
        $user->avatar = (!empty($user_profile->photoURL)) ? $user_profile->photoURL : "";
        $user->role = "public";
        $user->provider = $provider;
        $user->provider_uid = $user_profile->identifier;
        $user->gender = !empty($user_profile->gender) ? (($user_profile->gender == 'male') ? 'm' : 'f') : "";
        $user->email = !empty($user_profile->email) ? $user_profile->email : "";
        $user->password = $user_profile->identifier;
        $user->link = $user_profile->profileURL;
        $user->avatar = $user_profile->photoURL;
        //$user->confirm_password = $user_profile->identifier;
        $user->tmp_hash = $tmp_hash;
        $user->isverified = (!empty($user_profile->emailVerified)) ? 1 : 0;
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);

        debug($user);

       $this->Users->save($user);
       //debug($this->Users->invalidFields()); // he don't know invalidFields()
```

How can i show sql statement or something to debug and find the issue ?
        die('2');

Comment: Try to enable the DebugKit of CakePHP-3, there you can see the SQL statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution..
The problem is `errors()` before saving it doesn't contain any message..
But after saving it show the errors..
Liket that:
    `$this->Users->save($user);`

```
debug($user->errors());
```

Now i can sees the problems that i have .. these problems is due to unique validation..